# Merge multiple fragments of video and mux it to normal video format

Tags: merge, video-streaming

i want to ask if there is any option to just merge multiple fragments downloaded from HBO GO app and mux it to some normal format like mkv or mp4???  Because these fragments has no file type.  Some script, program, guide ??? It looks like this 
for video: **Fragments(video=0), Fragments(video=10000000), Fragments(video=20000000), Fragments(video=30000000), Fragments(video=40000000), Fragments(video=50000000)**

...for audio **Fragments(audio_eng_st_dub=0), Fragments(audio_eng_st_dub=20201361), Fragments(audio_eng_st_dub=40402721), Fragments(audio_eng_st_dub=60604082)**

...for text is simillar.
youtube-dl doesnt support HBO GO direct download so if anybody can help me with it ???
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

They are probably fragmented mp4, You can just concat them with the init fragment and many players can play it.

However HBO use DRM, so you will never be able to play these files.

Comment: I know about DRM, i tried download it througt ismdownloader. It downloaded nothing. I tried a different way and finally i have luck and downloaded the whole stream. I expect that this won't work but i just want to try it. So you are saying to concat them. But how ? I tried ffmpeg througt cmd but i cannot write working script. These files has no exception. It's "fragment" dot nothing. Mediainfo doesnt recognise any media info however i rename file and add .mp4 or .mkv. so please help me how to concat it. Thank you